# How to set custom icon in outlook IPM.Document item

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am creating a IPM.Document item using c# code. my sample code is below.

```
objDocItem = objFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Document");
objDocItem.Subject = "FileName.txt";
objDocItem.Save();
```

[image: Item Display in outlook]
I want to change my custom icon in above display item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is determined by the message class, which in turn is determined by the extension. E.g. for a .txt file, the extension (txt) is used to read the default value from the `HKCR\.txt` registry key. That default value is "txtfile", which means the message class will be `IPM.Document.txtfile`. You must remember to add the attachment as well. Take a look at existing document items with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (click IMessage button).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option, it exposes the [RDODocumentItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdodocumentitem.htm) object, which sets the message class as well as other available properties (such as Author, etc. from the old IStorage based Office files such as .doc, .xls, etc.) in a single call:

```
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
 set Msg = Folder.Items.Add("IPM.Document")
 Msg.SetDocument("c:\Temp\test.txt")
 Msg.Save
```

Comment: I have checked with PropertyAccessor to set icon.
i am able to set default icon provided by outlook. but i want to set my custom icon in document item. but i am not able to set that icon can u please help me.


i am not using Redemption.

Comment: You cannot do that. You can register your own custom file extension along with the custom icon to be show by Windows Explorer, but Outlook specific icon is only show for the custom Outlook forms based on the message class.